# Why aren't my org-links being htmlized?

Tags: org-mode

I use `org-mode` combined with `htmlize` to maintain my personal webpage. For example, I have a directory

```
webpage/
├── bar.pdf
└── foo.org

0 directories, 2 files
```

I want to link to the file `bar.pdf` in the org file `foo.org`. My `foo.org` file is

```
#+Title: testing htmlize links

This is a link to [[./bar.pdf]].
```

When I `htmlize` the file `foo.org` the output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!-- Created by htmlize-1.47 in css mode. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo.org</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      body {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
      .org-document-info-keyword {
        /* org-document-info-keyword */
        color: #ffff00;
      }
      .org-document-title {
        /* org-document-title */
        color: #afeeee;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #00ffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      a {
        color: inherit;
        background-color: inherit;
        font: inherit;
        text-decoration: inherit;
      }
      a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
<span class="org-document-info-keyword">#+Title:</span> <span class="org-document-title">testing htmlize links
</span>
This is a link to <span class="org-link"><a href="nil:nil">./bar.pdf</a></span>.
</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is with the line

```
    This is a link to <span class="org-link"><a href="nil:nil">./bar.pdf</a></span>.
```

Somehow `htmlize` is linking to `"nil:nil"` instead of `./bar.pdf`. What's going on here?

Issuing `M-x org-version` yields

```
Org mode version 9.0 (release_9.0-16-g8826f2 @ /home/brian/elisp/org-mode/lisp/)
```

I think `org version 9.0` may have changed how links work and `htmlize` is not cooperating. If this is so, how can I fix my problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want htmlize, instead of exporting Org to HTML? HTML export does convert Org links to HTML links, as you want; it also turns the `#+TITLE` into an HTML document title (notice htmlize left the `#+` in the output, and used `foo.org` as the title), etc..

I think the purpose of  `htmlize` is to produce a nicely formatted HTML representation of some source code. People use `htmlize` to include source code listings in HTML documents, for example. I think here `htmlize` is just using the `<a>` tag as a way to get the link styled as a link.

Comment: I actually do want to use `htmlize`. I have scripts that take care of the issues you mention. I should also mention that this issue is new--before updating to org 9.0 I did not have this problem.

Comment: This is a bug in org 9 right now. The htmlize link is constructed from a type and path that is not correct for that kind of link.

I will send a fix to the developers. 

If you have a fuzzy link, what should it look like? eg. [[tag]] that refers to a table name.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fix  your file links for now.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(org-link-set-parameters nil :htmlize-link
             (lambda ()
               (let* ((link (org-element-context))
                  (type (org-element-property :type  link))
                  (path (org-element-property :path link)))
                 (list :uri (format "%s:%s" type path)))))
#+END_SRC
```